# Discord.py Automatically assign roles to users having specific keyword in their status or if they have specific tag in username

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

can we do like if any of our members put "ideal army op" in status than they will automatically assigned a role like server supporter role?
or
and if they put "IA" in username they get a special role (which role id i put)

is this possible?
i am new to discord.py so i want help about it

Comment: I mean if they put "IA" Tag in their username than auto role and i want to make a bot with these 2 commands only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the event listener `on_member_update`.
There you can check if `after.status` is equal to the status you want, and if `after.name` or `after.nick` contains the tag you want.
And if either of those things are true, give them the role.

Read more here:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#discord.on_member_update
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#discord.Member.status
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#discord.Member.nick